# Make me able to choose which images/videos received via WhatsApp to show in my Google Photos Gallery?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, gallery, google-photos

I am having a problem that drives me crazy. Coming from iOS I had my Photo Gallery, and separated from that I had my WhatsApp App with its chats and images. When I wanted to save some of those images friends sent me, I tapped them and saved them to the Gallery. Now on my Galaxy Note 10 either ALL images received by ALL chats are also shown in my Google Photos App or none of them and within WhatsApp I am TOTALLY unable to safe choosen images manually to my Google Photos Gallery. They do not show up on the Gallery nor any Album.

This drives me crazy!!! Who would want all images one receives beeing shown in the gallery? And who would not be able to store some chosen images to the gallery? How comes Android completely rides aside an obvious desire of a common user?

Is there any solution to this?

Note: I am not talking about automatic download of media in WhatsApp. I am talking about selectively/manually showing/saving media to my Google Photos Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp saves - all photos which are downloaded - to the WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images folder. 
The way gallery apps work on Android is that they scan internal storage and any folder which has media files in it are shown in the gallery app. So, similarly, the WhatsApp Media folder shows up for you in the Google Photos app.

Your few options are:

- You can copy items from the WhatsApp Media folder and move them to
  another folder.
- You can manually stop media from *certain* chats from appearing in your Gallery app. You can set that in chat settings and WhatsApp will move these files to a folder with `.nomedia` attribute set. So, this media will not show in any gallery app (except file managers).
- You can disable all media from all chats from appearing in your Gallery apps. In this case, if you need to specifically save some media items, you will need to manually copy those items from the *nomedia* folders to your main folder. You will need a file manager for this task.

Comment: ok, so basically no solution to this. Just crazy that android does not provide such an essential feature.